# I want to feed the results of a clustering into a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, clustering

Basically, my problem is, I have a dataset where I know about 12% of the rows should be classified as something, and I have some reasonable predictors. The problem is, my predictors aren't too good, because when I run a K-means with two clusters, they classify 85% of the rows as target instead of 12%. But otherwise the centroids elaborated seem to have face validity.

My idea is that I could feed the cluster assignments and the predictors into a logistic regression, and then I could fine tune the acceptance threshold to 12% instead of 50%. Mathematically, it seems like it should work but it reeks of inelegance.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is determined by the "geometry" of your data, i.e. by the "distances" between your data points, where "distance" is meant to be understood very broadly here. Classification, in your case I guess binary classification, is determined by the labels $\{0, 1\}$ of your data points.

There doesn't have to be any relation between the labels and the clustering of your data. E.g., you could have something like this:

[image]

Here, the blue points are labeled with $0$ and the red ones with $1$. This shows a situation where you have two clusters above each other, but this has nothing to do with the labels.

Thus, I would not get distracted by the clustering via k-means and would concentrate on classification alone. If your labels cannot be separated linearly, think about other classification methods, e.g. kernel logistic regression or SVM.

Having said that, the geometry can sometimes contain some indication about the labeling. And, if one knows about that, one can use this, via [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning), to improve the classification. But one needs some evidence, e.g. via domain knowledge, that this connection between geometry and labeling is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I have no labels, just approximate domain knowledge of what an ideal example is, with a bunch of data that is actually linear in nature and inultiole dimensions spans the gamut. I was hoping clustering would see what I couldn't but it wasn't helpful. It maybe because I need better predictors, or maybe because my ideal example is not very common. But I think at 12% of the idealest examples I would get close to the truth, given the limitations of my data.

Comment: So you don't have labels and clustering isn't aligned with what you want, either. But you do have some "approximate domain knowledge" (adk) of what would be an ideal candidate for label "one" in binary classification. Since this adk is the only thing you have, try to assign an "adk score" to as many data points as possible, then choose a threshold for that score to assign the labels zero and one to this subset of scored points and use this to train some binary classifier.